# Should I edit my question or create a new one?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, editing

I asked [a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44636/can-warforged-be-repaired-with-a-skill-check) with a straightforward title and a mostly straightforward body, and got a straightforward answer, which I accepted because they answered the question as I wrote it.

But I failed to make in clear I was interested in more than just that narrow answer. Perhaps a better question would have been "What are all the ways to heal a living construct?" or "How can we make up for a Warforged's lack of healing?"

Should I go back and edit the question to broaden it, or should I ask a new question? The base question seems to stand on it's own but it's answer would be encompassed by the broader question.

Comment: Related: [Rewriting questions after question has been answered](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/rewriting-questions-after-question-has-been-answered)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ask a new question, definitely. When the question changes *substantially*, it's cleaner and preferred to make a new question.

The existing question is done and editing it now would create a bit of a mess, what with an answer already being accepted and answering a different question. Further, the question is a decent one by itself, so although it might not be the one you meant to ask, it's a good question and doesn't deserve deletion.

---

For the new question, note that of the two example titles you floated, one is *much* better than the other. **"How can we make up for a Warforged's lack of healing?"** describes your actual problem: the Warforged's lack of healing.

Meanwhile, **"What are all the ways to heal a living construct?"** is pretty general, and there's no guarantee that it will even solve your problem as it's likely to get answers along the lines of "well construct X can be healed by X1, construct Y can be healed by Y1 and Y2..." with perhaps none of them mentioning Warforged! You could end up in the same place again, with good answers to a solid question, but nothing that actually helps your actual situation.

So if you post a new question, it should be along the lines of "How can we make up for a Warforged's lack of healing?" That's a good title to start from to write a nicely focused question that will solve the problem you're actually facing.

Comment: X/Y problem, basically

Answer (score 4):

I would open a new one, starting with something on the line of "I asked in a previous question about using craft to repair constructs. Are there other ways..." and so on. I don't know if there's a site policy on that but it looks not like a duplicate to me